# Limiting work in progress of parallel operations of a streamed resource

Tags: c#-4.0, concurrency, task-parallel-library, yield-return

I've found myself recently using the `SemaphoreSlim` class to limit the work in progress of a parallelisable operation on a (large) streamed resource:

```
// The below code is an example of the structure of the code, there are some 
// omissions around handling of tasks that do not run to completion that should be in production code

SemaphoreSlim semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(Environment.ProcessorCount * someMagicNumber);
foreach (var result in StreamResults()) 
{
  semaphore.Wait();
  var task = DoWorkAsync(result).ContinueWith(t => semaphore.Release());
  ...
}
```

This is to avoid bringing too many results into memory and the program being unable to cope (generally evidenced via an OutOfMemoryException). Though the code works and is reasonably performant, it still feels ungainly. Notably the `someMagicNumber` multiplier, which although tuned via profiling, may not be as optimal as it could be and isn't resilient to changes to the implementation of `DoWorkAsync`.

In the same way that thread pooling can overcome the obstacle of scheduling many things for execution, I would like something that can overcome the obstacle of scheduling many things to be loaded into memory based on the resources that are available.

Since it is deterministically impossible to decide whether an OutOfMemoryException will occur, I appreciate that what I'm looking for may only be achievable via statistical means or even not at all, but I hope that I'm missing something.

Comment: Would you mind if `DoWorkAsync()` was actually executed synchronously? Can you use C# 5? How is this related to `yield return`?

Comment: @svick I would rather DoWorkAsync was not executed synchronously since network IO is performed and completion port threads can be used. yield-return was tagged simply because it is how the results from `StreamResults` are returned. I cannot use .C#5 (or 4.5, or whichever version MS are calling it now!), just C#4.0

Comment: It's called C# 5.0 and it will be released together with .Net 4.5. Yes, .Net version numbers can get confusing.

Comment: If it's doing network IO, then it's pretty much up to you to find the correct degree of parallelism. The `ThreadPool` (or anything in the TPL) can't really do that for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I'd say that you're probably overthinking this problem.  The consequences for overshooting are rather high (the program crashes).  The consequences for being too low are that the program *might* be slowed down.  As long as you still have some buffer beyond a minimum value, further increases to the buffer will generally have little to no effect, unless the processing time of that task in the pipe is extraordinary volatile.

If your buffer is constantly filling up it generally means that the task before it in the pipe executes quite a bit quicker than the task that follows it, so even without a fairly small buffer it is likely to always ensure the task following it has some work.  The buffer size needed to get 90% of the benefits of a buffer is usually going to be quite small (a few dozen items maybe) whereas the side needed to get an OOM error are like 6+ *orders of magnate* higher.  As long as you're somewhere in-between those two numbers (and that's a pretty big range to land in) you'll be just fine.

Just run your static tests, pick a static number, maybe add a few percent extra for "just in case" and you should be good.  At most, I'd move some of the magic numbers to a config file so that they can be altered without a recompile in the event that the input data or the machine specs change radically.

Comment: I think the question is not about size of a buffer, it's about executing things in parallel.

Comment: @svick It's about both.  There are a number of dependant operations, running in parallel, creating pipe.  When one task finishes a unit of work it passes the result to the next task, which does another unit of work on it, and passes it to the next operator in the pipe.  All of these tasks are working at the same time.  There is a buffer between each of the tasks so that they don't need to wait for a result to be received by the next task before starting on the next unit of work; this reduces wait time if the tasks all don't take exactly the same amount of time to do their work.

Comment: I'm not certain what are you talking about, but I'm quite sure it's not the code in question. That doesn't have any pipeline or anything like that.